# Connecting to aws s3 bucket with a private rsa

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3

I have a third party vendor that hosts an s3 bucket for me here:

```
s3://base/my_bucket/
```

Recently, the vendor put in place requirements that users need to go through a secure connection (upload public RSA to their site and have private RSA local).

My private RSA lives in `~/.ssh/vendor_creds`

When I look at `aws s3 cp` documentation, I do not see anything about pushing with that request the location of my local RSA I want to use.

Further, `aws config` does not ask for any specific token locations.

From the vendor, I have:

1. Access Key ID
2. Secret Key
3. An s3 url

The command that I have which was working previously was: `aws s3 cp s3://base/my_bucket/ /home/my_sername/temp/AWS/  --recursive`

Scratching my head a bite and would appreciate any help.

For context, the vendor said I should use cyberduck to download the data (aka: manually every day....)

Comment: What does RSA have to do with S3? Is this a bucket on AWS cloud?

Comment: S3 does not support using a local RSA private key to encrypt data.  If this is a feature CyberDuck supports, it is doing the encryption before sending data to S3, so you'd have to investigate how it does this.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Yes a bucket on AWS cloud. The vendor made me generate a public/private RSA pair.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I have every reason to think the vendor is technically quite sad.

Comment: S3 only supports AES 256 bit encryption not asymmetric encryption like RSA. If data must be RSA encrypted, then data must be encrypted on the client side and all cryptography would be transparent to AWS S3. I think RSA is overkill for secure storage of data on S3 at rest. You will be responsible for protecting and managing of any keys you generate. AWS managed encryption is better and certified. Do be careful with your data around that vendor.

Comment: The requirement of "users need to go through a secure connection" is unrelated to encrypting data stored in Amazon S3. Please provide the _exact_ requirements provided by the vendor because it is possible that they are not actually requesting what you think.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein This wound up being the case and I provided the solution for my exact problem below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my specific use-case, I needed to do the below. Hopefully helpful to someone else in the future.

```
sftp -i ~/.ssh/token_rsa -r {USER}.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:{Some Additional}/{info}*
```

My additional info was specific url parameters provided by the vendor.